# gammu - No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected

Tags: android, mobile, sms, galaxy, gammu

What do I do wrong?

```
$ gammu-detect
; Configuration file generated by gammu-detect.
; Please check The Gammu Manual for more information.

[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyACM0
name = samsung GT-N7105
connection = at
<...>

$ cat /etc/gammurc 
[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyACM0
connection = at
model = auto
$ echo 'test' | gammu --sendsms TEXT 11111111111 -unicode -autolen 81 
No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that, but [Android phones are not supported by Gammu](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/faq/phone.html#are-android-phones-supported).